# Best way to raise progress events in a parallel file downloader while minimizing locking

Tags: c#, oop, parallel-processing

I am developing a small file downloader. It downloads file by segmenting it and then downloading each segment in parallel. I wanted my application to support an event system, which ideally would show the total progress done already.

My current naive approach is to simply lock the data structure in which all threads are storing info about their current progress every time each thread downloads 10k. I then do the calculation and then raise the event. This has the problem that the threads are going to generally all raise an events at the same time, and also that I'm locking the whole structure each time something I want to raise an event. On the other hand, if the connection gets slow, it can happen that it will take a while to raise events. I'd prefer to have a system which would raise an event each 100ms or something.

While the solution works, I'm not very happy with it. What would be the correct approach to the described situation?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) as the queue into which all your threads write their progress information. Then have another thread which exists just to dequeue items from the BlockingCollection

Your dequeuing thead could look like

```
foreach (var progressMessage in progressMessageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // Handle progressMessage by raising an event.
}
```

And assuming you have a class called `ProgressMessage` which encapsulates the progress information, you would declare the queue like:

```
BlockingCollection<ProgressMessage> progressMessageQueue = new BlockingCollection<ProgressMessage>();
```

You'd add items to the queue so:

```
progressMessageQueue.Add(progressMessage);
```

And when you know that all the threads have finished their work, call:

```
progressMessageQueue.CompleteAdding();
```

As far as queueing progress messages every so many milliseconds goes; that's a lot harder. You'd have to have some kind of timeout handling if the file chunks didn't download quickly enough. I've no idea how you would do that, since I don't know how you're downloading the files.